# Suggest some arts schools for post-graduate in other field?

Tags: career, education

I have a bachelors and masters degree in Civil Engineering(Final yr Master's student). My hobby is playwriting. Now, I would like to pursue a career in arts. So, I'm looking for some universities which offer degree in playwriting/screen-writing and direction.

I have no clue about where to get started. So, I request you guys to guide me.

**Edit:** I don't have any degree pertaining to arts now. So, I don't know if I'm eligible for masters. May be I need a bachelors degree first.

Comment: Do you mean for a Masters of Fine Arts in writing, or...?

Comment: @justkt: I have edited the post. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you ought to understand that outside of professional degrees, engineering degrees, and a few others masters degrees are often a negative return on investment - they cost more than they benefit.  Make sure to do a careful analysis before deciding on such a degree, or have a cash flow source that you're willing to spend for little return.

If you decide that you want to pursue such a degree, you will want to start searching for a masters of fine arts in playwriting or screenwriting.  Websites such as [universities.com](http://www.universities.com/edu/Masters_degrees_in_Playwriting_and_Screenwriting.html) will list school programs, and you can use that information to go to the program site and see what the requirements are.

Rather than limiting your focus to masters degrees, however, I would investigate the career path that most successful playwrights or screenwriters have taken and see if an MFA is absolutely required, because it is quite likely to not be a net gain.

Comment: Is it directly possible to get a MFA degree without a bachelors in arts? I doubt it. I guess you are right about the ups and downs. I will weigh up the situation accordingly but if I need to start, do I need to have a bachelors in arts?

Comment: @sarath - I am not an admissions officer at any school with an MFA (or anywhere at all).  That is why I provided a link in my answer to a listing of schools with an MFA.  Visit their websites and look at admissions information.  I imagine it will vary, but my brief glances showed that you can find programs that merely require any undergraduate degree.